# open another View controller without replacing the background of first View controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

in my `viewcontroller1` i have a imageview  (as background) and i want to open another viewcontroller without replacing   `viewcontroller1`'s background

in below images you can see that there's a image 
and when we move to another viewcontroller the background didnt change , any clue how can i achieve this ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a transparent background for your second viewcontroller.

Comment: didnt worked ? all black now , @onnoweb

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a plain `UIViewController` with a `UIImageView` as background image.
2. Add above a `UINavigationController`.
3. Set `UINavigationController`, ViewController1 and ViewController2 background color to `UIColor.clearColor()`
4. Set `UINavigationBar` background transparent:

   ```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
   ```

Comment: @remyboys I updated the answer, the imageview is below the Navigation controller..can you do it? you have to add the navigation controller in the main view controller which has the image view as background

Comment: hey man @Marco i'm not getting what you're saying ,  i have a ViewController with navigationController embedded in it , then i have a Transparent navigation bar but what next ? how i'm gonna have background for both VCs ??

Comment: @remyboys I updated the answer, let me know if it is possible for you

Comment: hey man i just did what you said in this dummy project  http://expirebox.com/download/a12ba2e821cdd6496bc07cdd2d17769b.html please check it ,